# How to avoid the login screen when returning from standby?

Tags: windows-7, login, user-accounts, standby

When my computer comes out of standby mode. It still ask me which user I am. Still, I'm the only user. So this seems a bit useless.

[image]

How can I prevent this extra click? Standby settings don't seem to cope with: "don't show login screen". I just want standby to log into my profile right away. **I have no password set**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Power Options and select your active Plans settings and go to advanced settings

the Option `Require a password on wakeup` should be set as `No`

See if this fixes your problem, you will need to do this for all plans that are used on your system.